# Webhook not posting to URL

Tags: php, curl, webhooks

I have a Webhook I am trying to configure. A user fills out a form, and it is connected to a Webhook as well to send the form data to another location. Doesnt seem to be working, when I submit the form, the webhook destination doesn't seem to be processing/sending the data.

Here is the Json Data:

```
    data.json   { "Account_Name": [ "Test Name" ], "Email": [ "test@test.com" ], "Phone": [ "5555555555" ], "camp_id": [ "18052" ], "hs_a_t": [ "1360223458579" ], "ip_address": [ "" ], "referrer": [ "" ], "source": [ "3" ], "time_submitted": [ "07:51 AM UTC" ] }
    data.xml    <?xml version='1.0'?> <form_data> <Account_Name>Test Name</Account_Name> <Phone>5555555555</Phone> <Email>test@test.com</Email> <camp_id>18052</camp_id> <hs_a_t>1360223458579</hs_a_t> <source>3</source> <referrer/> <ip_address></ip_address> <time_submitted>07:51 AM UTC</time_submitted> </form_data>
    extra_data.json { "rapleaf": {} }
    extra_data.xml  <?xml version='1.0'?> <extra_data> <rapleaf/> </extra_data>
    page_id a75948fc-70f6-11e2-8dd8-12313e008101
    page_name   Test
    page_url    http://unbouncepages.com/test33333
    variant a
```

Here is the php code the webhook points to:

```
    <?php 
    function stripslashes_deep($value) {
    $value = is_array($value) ?
    array_map('stripslashes_deep', $value) :
    stripslashes($value);

    return $value;
    }

    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $unescaped_post_data = stripslashes_deep($_POST);
    } else {
    $unescaped_post_data = $_POST;
    }
    $form_data = json_decode($unescaped_post_data['data_json']);

    /*******************************
PARSE DATA FROM UNBOUNCE
    *******************************/
    $email_address          = $form_data->email[0];
    $page_id            = $_POST['page_id'];                              //Unbounce Page ID
    $page_url           = $_POST['page_url'];                       //Unbounce Page URL
    $variant            = $_POST['variant'];                        //Unbounce Page Variant   


    function mytheme_post_to_another_script($form)
    {

// Rewrite the post variables

$post = array(

    'Account_Name' => $_POST['name'], // Change iphorm_X_X to name field unique ID

    'Email' => $_POST['email_address'], // Change iphorm_X_X to email field unique ID

    'Phone' => $_POST['phone_number'], // Change iphorm_X_X to phone field unique ID

    'Website_URL' => $_POST['iphorm_1_4'],

    'Camp_ID' => $_POST['Camp_ID'],

    'Source' => $_POST['Source'],

'Email_List_ID' => $_POST['Email_List_ID'],

    'hs_a_t' => $_POST['hs_a_t']

);



// Create a new cURL resource

$ch = curl_init();



// Set URL and other appropriate options

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://Reports.rankupmedia.com/Client/Sales/Lead/');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));



// Grab URL and pass it to the browser

curl_exec($ch);



// Close cURL resource, and free up system resources

curl_close($ch);

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: have you tried getting the output that curl gets when posting the data?

Comment: No I havnt tried that yet